# derivation of a function with a function as an argument

Tags: derivatives

i have function $V(x(t))=\frac{x''}{x}$ where ' is derivative with respect to time. i want to find $\frac{dV(x(t))}{dx}$

what i have tried is $\frac{x'''}{x}-\frac{x''x'}{x^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

First find $\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{xx'''-x'x''}{x^2}$

Using the fact that $\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{dv}{dx}•\frac{dx}{dt}, $

We get  $\frac{dv}{dx} = \frac{\frac{dv}{dt}}{ \frac{dx}{dt}}=\frac{(xx'''-x'x'')}{x'x^2}$

Comment: i want to find $\frac{dv}{dx}$ but you find $\frac{dv}{dt}$ .

Comment: sorry I got typos in the answer, It has been fixed

Comment: i think time derivative of $v$ is $\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{xx'''-x'x''}{x^2}$

Comment: Haha my answer is full of mistakes. Sorry guys